# To change group image(what's the _calcBounds() do?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

When we want to change the src,we can use setElement().

The Example such like

```
`https://jsbin.com/lowuqezofu/1/edit?html,js,output`
```

It changes when we click the button at the bottom.

But when I add the image to the group like

```
`https://jsbin.com/xerureviwe/edit?html,js,output`
```

I want to use _CalcBounds() to update the group,but it runs error.
So I find the other document to solve it.

[Here](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3831) is the people who have related questions on it.

Because I haven't see this function on official tutorial of website.

I think I may not make some mistake.
If we don't need addWithUpdate() or removeWithUpdate() just set image src,is this method can do update function we want?

If not,is there any alternative to do this way?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for others view the question.
However,I haven't find the suitable solution yet.

I use **addWithUpdate()** and **removeWithUpdate()** stupidly instead of using **_calcbounds()** which function I don't really understand.

It's not a good answer indeed.

But non-perfect solution can solve our problem,that's enough.

Thanks everyone again and please forgive my poor English.

Comment: You want to change image src inside group?

Comment: @Durga Yes.I want change src of image inside group.